# How to draw text with an image background with OpenGL and FreeType-gl

Tags: opengl

I am using FreeType-gl to draw text with a background of an image. I indeed could draw them separately. However, when I draw the text after drawing the background, the background image will be overwritten by the text with a uniform background color, even I don't use glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) to clean before the text drawing.

I am wondering why the text drawing couldn't have a transparent background?

Comment: The question would be more helpful if you included the code.

Comment: It depends how you're using Freetype.  The way I use it is to put glyphs into a texture.  The glyph bitmap is a single 8 bit channel.  When I draw the glyph, blending is switched on.  Just multiplying the 8 bit value with a font colour and blend it with the screen works OK.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have fixed the problem, though. I didn't aware that I cleaned the buffer before I draw the text. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I aware that the buffer was cleaned before the text drawing. In other words, there shouldn't be buffer cleaning (i.e., glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)) between the background and text drawing, in the drawing loop.